# Horizontal line without vertical gap

Tags: spacing, rules

I'm trying to create a underlined heading like this, without space between John Smith and the underline

[image]

I tried this command, but it adds a vertical gap between the name and the underline

```
\noindent\rule[0ex]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}
```

Comment: Hove you tried overlapping them, using \rlap and possibly \raisebox?

Comment: The `[0ex]` in your command is telling TeX you want the rule raised by 0ex. Perhaps something like `[2ex]` would suit you better.

Comment: Hell World, or Hello World? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\makebox[0pt][l]{\Large\bfseries John Smith}%%
\rule[-0.5ex]{\columnwidth}{0.4pt}

Hell world, this is my cover letter.

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are commands like `\rlap` and `\\lap`.  But, I think `\makebox` is kind of fun.  You can set the width of the box and the alignment to be *left, right,* or *center*.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\rule[-0.5ex]{\columnwidth}{0.4pt}%%
\hspace*{-\dimexpr\columnwidth/2}%%
\makebox[0pt]{\Large\bfseries John Smith}%%
\hspace*{\dimexpr\columnwidth/2}%%

Hell world, this is my cover letter.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Following this general idea, you can create nice commands like the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifaeShowAnswers
\newcommand\aeShowAnswer[2]{%%
  \rule[-0.5ex]{#1}{0.4pt}%%
  \hspace*{-\dimexpr#1/2}%%
  \makebox[0pt]{\ifaeShowAnswers#2\fi}%%
  \hspace*{\dimexpr#1/2}}

%%\aeShowAnswerstrue

\begin{document}

Lord \aeShowAnswer{1.25in}{Voldemort} is the \aeShowAnswer{1.25in}{Harry Potter}'s archnemesis.

\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

By uncommending the line with `\aeShowAnswerstrue` results in

[image]

Comment: Or: `John Smith\par \rule[2ex]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}` (with `\noindent`s as appropriate -- hard to say in OP's question how `\parindent` is working). --- Love the "Hell world" though: how all cover letters should start!

Comment: @jon regarding "Hell world", just following the OP's lead, but *really* I couldn't resist.

Comment: .... Ha, indeed!