# Writting text over a \line

Tags: positioning, text

I have an worksheet that my students had to answer. In that worksheet I placed a field that they could write their name on with the `\line` command.

Now I am preparing the answer sheet, so they can see the correct answers on a .pdf file, and I'd like to type "Answer Sheet" on top of that `\line` command I used before. Simply writing it "pushes" the line to the right, but doesn't do it on top of it.

The code for my "name field" inside a MWE is as follows. The "name" field is to the right of the word "Nome", since that's portuguese for "name". The `\textnumero` code is there because it produces a nice-looking number symbol and it's intended that the student writes his student-number on the right of it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

  \fbox{

    \begin{minipage}{0.90\linewidth}

    \vspace*{0.30cm} Nome: \line(1,0){260} \ \textnumero:\line(1,0){25}

    \end{minipage}

    }

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think, this is much easier with a `tabular` environment

Comment: Would I be able to make the name field larger than the number field?

Comment: It might be of interest to consider [my post to another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290673/22413).  Toward the end of my posted answer, I show a way to create answer spaces to be filled in later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can insert the text over the line using `\rlap`.  but then the line will overprint the bottom of the inserted text, so you have to raise the text a bit.

this uses that approach.  you can adjust the lift to suit.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

  \fbox{

    \begin{minipage}{0.90\linewidth}

    \vspace*{0.30cm} Nome: \raisebox{.2ex}{\rlap{Answer sheet}}{\line(1,0){260}} \ \textnumero:\line(1,0){25}

    \end{minipage}

    }

\end{document}
```

[image]

egreg points out (rightly) that using `\makebox` instead of `\rlap` is more
in the spirit of latex, and may avoid some problems.  here's the one changed line and the output:

```
\vspace*{0.30cm} Nome: 
  \raisebox{.2ex}{\makebox[0pt][l]{Answer sheet}}{\line(1,0){260}} \ %
  \textnumero:\line(1,0){25}
```

[image]

finally, there's an alternate approach, using an underline, which drops the
line below the text baseline:

```
\vspace*{0.30cm} 
  Nome: \underline{\makebox[260pt][l]{Answer sheet}} \ %
  \textnumero:\underline{\makebox[25pt]{ }}
```

[image]

Comment: `\makebox[0pt][l]{Answer sheet}` avoids the peculiarities of `\rlap`.

Comment: @barbara is it possible to make a longer portion of text be underlined? (like 3 line paragraph with hyphenation)

Comment: @GuilhermeVargas -- there may be a package that underlines multiple lines with hyphenation, but it's not possible with a simple approach like this one.  that sounds like a problem for a new question.  (you can refer to this one, and say that the new question is an extension.)  i've made multi-line forms that permitted hyphenated text, but the lines on the form were preprinted, and the text was set in a very controlled manner to fill in the existing form.  i don't think that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}    
\begin{document}

\noindent
\fbox{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule]{%
    \rule{0pt}{3ex} Nome: \hrulefill~\textnumero:\rule{2cm}{0.4pt}}}

\bigskip
\noindent 
\fbox{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule]{%
        \rule{0pt}{3ex} Nome: Answer Sheet\hrulefill~\textnumero:\rule{2cm}{0.4pt}}}

\bigskip
\noindent 
\fbox{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule]{%
        \rule{0pt}{3ex} Nome: \rlap{Answer Sheet}\hrulefill~\textnumero:\rule{2cm}{0.4pt}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's not quite it. I want the "answer sheet" phrase to be written over the line that is to the right of the word "Nome"

Comment: inside or outside of the frame?

Comment: Inside it, kinda like as if "Answer Sheet" was the "name" of the student.

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: Looks nice, but the big issue is making the line go "under" the "Answer Sheet" words. Notice how the line starts right after the "Answer Sheet"

Comment: again: see edited answer